# Extracting variable from onchange event handler for use in other functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, event-handling

I have an event handler listening for a change in a dropdown and setting the value of a variable. I have declared the variable as global i.e. outside of any functions, and then set the value on change. However, once it has changed I need to be able to pick up the variable in other functions (not within the even handler). How can i 'extract' it from within the event handler? I've tried to return it but no luck - here is the code:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select#search_subject', function () {
    if ($('#sBar3').show()) {
        $('#sBar3').hide();
    }
    var subject = $('#search_subject>option:selected').text();
    var id = $('#search_subject>option:selected').val();
    ajaxSubject(subject, '#sBar3');
    return subject;
});
console.log(subject);
```

the log just shows 'empty string' and I'm baffled. If possible I dont want to rejig the code to include everything within the event handler (there's lots of Google Map generating code in there and it will make for a pain) - i just need to get the subject variable out of the event handler if that makes sense - Thanks

Comment: You said you declared the variable in global scope. Then don't declare a local variable with the same name, omit `var`. Of course the `console.log(subject);` will still show `undefined` since the event hasn't happened yet at the moment the statement is executed.

Comment: thanks for helping a total noob understand a little more felix - cheers

Comment: `subject=$("option:selected",this).text();`

Comment: @mplungjan for that matter, `var id = $(this).val();`

Comment: @Mathletics yes, as I posted in my answer :)

Comment: @Mathletics - arent you again declaring a local variable with var?

Comment: @Mobaz yes, but the question didn't indicate a need for `id` to be global... though upon reading the function, I see that it likely _should_ be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using the `var` keyword, you're creating a new local variable, which you're then assigning the subject text to.  If you've already defined `subject` in the global scope, then your assignment line should simply be:

```
subject = $('#search_subject>option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the select is not created later, then this would be simpler code after you remove the `var` that makes subject local

```
$("#search_subject").on('change',function () {
  $('#sBar3').toggle();
  subject = $('option:selected',this).text();
  var id = $(this).val(); // not used?
  ajaxSubject(subject, '#sBar3');
  window.console && console.log(subject);   
  return subject;
});
```